# Radio Button Binding not Working

Tags: jquery

I have created a loop of div's and there are some radiobuttons on the page

Each radio button corresponds to a div. So if the loop is at position 2, radio 2 is selected and so on. Vice-versa if the radio 3 is selected, the div 3 gets selected, something like a 2-way binding.

```
function anim_loop(index) {
    if(timer){
        $elements.filter('.current').stop(true, true).hide().removeClass('current');
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    $radios.eq(index).prop('checked', true);
    $elements.eq(index).stop(true, true).addClass('current').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('current');
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            timer = undefined;
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

I also have a left and right button on the page which also manipulates the loop.

There are **two specific bugs** that I am not able to fix:

1. When the loop reaches 4th radio, I have to click the Right button *twice* to make it move to the next element, in our case, 1st radio. Not sure why
2. You have to be quick to replicate this bug at your end. Just when the loop is moving from 3rd to 4th and 4th starts getting selected, immediately click on 2. A strange thing happens! The text below the radio gets overlapped and the loop instead of going from 2 to 3, now goes back to 1. Not sure why this is happening. Can anybody help me out

http://jsfiddle.net/69nk3/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are sending 4 as the index.
Add a check for this at the start of your anim_loop function.

```
function anim_loop(index) {
    if(index == $elements.length){
        index = 0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69nk3/3/

Comment: Thanks, bug 2 still exists :(

Comment: that is because you then have 2 with the "current" class at the same time. You can see this by watching it in firebug. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, it is hard to fix your code